# Логи выполнения pg_dump из docker контейнера

Tags: postgresql, логирование, резервное-копирование, crontab

Есть вот такая команда, стягивающая дамп базы postgres из докера в хост.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

docker exec db pg_dump -U postgres -Fc -v -d postgres | gzip -9 > /path/to/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).dump.gz
```

Выполняется она из crontab

```bsh
1 0 * * * /path/to/dump.sh >> /var/log/cron_backup.log
```

По итогу в `cron_backup.log` ничего не записывается. Каким образом ещё можно логировать выполнение `pg_dump` в файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_dump` пишет свой лог в stderr, а с теми опциями, что вы запускаете дамп выводится в stdout и он полностью попадает на вход gzip.

Так что нужно перенаправлять stderr, а не stdout:

```
1 0 * * * /path/to/dump.sh 2>>/var/log/cron_backup.log
```

Comment: Благодарю, output от ключа `-v` теперь пишется в лог-файл